# UWP - Insert data from the server (json) into the database with certain conditions

Tags: c#, json, database, sqlite, uwp

I have an app that checks the data on the server (json) and the database. I want when the id on json is not the same as the id on the database, it will insert all data with unequal id into the database.
Code:

```
var sqlpath = System.IO.Path.Combine(Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "ebookstore.db");
            this.DataContextChanged += (s, e1) => { UpdateViewModel = DataContext as ViewModels.UpdateViewModel; };
            string idDb = @"SELECT id FROM books where parent_folder_id = 2 and title like '%guru%'";

            var IDdb = objConnUpdate.Prepare(idDb);
            IDdb.Step();
            iddb = IDdb[0].ToString();
            IDDB = Convert.ToInt32(iddb.ToString());
            ConnectionProfile connections = NetworkInformation.GetInternetConnectionProfile();
            {
                            try
                            {
                                Downloading.IsOpen = true;
                                string urlPath1 = "https://.../fetch/k13G";
                                var httpClient1 = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler());
                                httpClient1.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("KIAT-API-KEY", "...*");
                                var values1 = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
                            {
                                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("halaman", "1"),
                                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("limit", "20"),
                            };

                                var response1 = await httpClient1.PostAsync(urlPath1, new FormUrlEncodedContent(values1));
                                response1.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

                                string jsonText1 = await response1.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                                JsonObject jsonObject1 = JsonObject.Parse(jsonText1);
                                JsonArray jsonData1 = jsonObject1["data"].GetArray();

                                foreach (JsonValue groupValue in jsonData1)
                                {
                                    JsonObject groupObject = groupValue.GetObject();

                                    string ID = groupObject["id"].GetString();

                                    BukuUpdate file1 = new BukuUpdate();
                                    file1.ID = ID;
                                    int intID = Convert.ToInt32(file1.ID);

                                    if (intID != IDDB)
                                    {

                                                string jumlahidDb = @"SELECT COUNT(id) FROM books where parent_folder_id = 2 and id > " + IDDB + " and title like '%guru%'";

                                                var jumlahIdDB = objConnUpdate.Prepare(jumlahidDb);
                                                jumlahIdDB.Step();
                                                if (jumlahiddb < jumlahbuku)
                                                {;
                                                    if (nama == "Kelas_01_SD_")
                                                    {
                                                        DownloadBukuK2013G(url);
                                                        string K2013GUpdate = @"INSERT INTO books (id,title,folder_id,identifier,parent_folder_id) SELECT " + intID + ",'" + namaFile + ".pdf',34,'" + namaFile +
                                                        ".pdf',2 WHERE not exists (select id AND title AND folder_id AND identifier AND parent_folder_id FROM books WHERE id=" + intID + " and title='" + namaFile +
                                                        ".pdf' AND folder_id=34 and identifier='" + namaFile + ".pdf' and parent_folder_id=2)";
                                                        var K2013GQuery = objConnUpdate.Prepare(K2013GUpdate);
                                                        K2013GQuery.Step();
                                                    }
```

BukuUpdate.cs:

```
public class BukuUpdate
{
        public string ID { get; set; }
}
```

Database:
[image: database stucture]

I did not succeed in implementing it. How to handle it?

Comment: So did you mean you post request to one server to get the data that with Json format, and want to parse the data to save to local database? If the data contains records that  id is same with the exist one, what did you will do, if not, what did you want to do? Could please also share your local database structure?

Comment: Yeah, I want if the id on json is not the same as the id on the database, then the data will be added to the database. If the same, then do nothing. My database structure adds to the above post.

Comment: I would like if the list of all ids in the database if not the same on the list of all the ids on json, it will insert the data into the database. But if I use the code in my previous post, it only shows the first id in the database (not the list of all the ids). How to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

> But if I use the code in my previous post, it only shows the first id in the database

You getting the first id by this code line `iddb = IDdb[0].ToString();` for using. Actually the `id` list is saved in `idDb` variable.

> I want if the id on json is not the same as the id on the database, then the data will be added to the database. If the same, then do nothing.

For this, you may just get all the `id`s from the database, and compare with the new income record from Json one by one. From your code snippet I'm not sure what's the Nuget package you're using for `Sqlite`, but the newest official tutorial using [`Microsoft.Data.SQLite`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Data.SQLite/) package. I also strongly recommended you to use `Microsoft.Data.SQLite` package by following the [official tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-access/sqlite-databases). By this way, the insert sample code may like this:

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{ 
    private void btngettest_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        List<String> ids = sqlhelp.GetData();
        string idfromjson = "2";
        foreach (string id in ids)
        {
            if (id != idfromjson)
            {
                //do insert operation
            }
            else
            {
                //do nothing
            }
        } 
    } 
}

public class sqlhelp
{
    public static void InitializeDatabase()
    {
       ... 
    }

    public static List<String> GetData()
    {
        List<String> entries = new List<string>();

        using (SqliteConnection db =
            new SqliteConnection("Filename=sqliteSample.db"))
        {
            db.Open();
            SqliteCommand selectCommand = new SqliteCommand
                ("SELECT id from MyTable", db);
            SqliteDataReader query = selectCommand.ExecuteReader();
            while (query.Read())
            {
                entries.Add(query.GetString(0));
            }
            db.Close();
        }
        return entries;
    }
```

Since your code snippet contains a lot of your own logic that I didn't give changes on your original code snippet. Please kindly reference my simple code which may be more clearly to know.

Comment: I've tried it, but there is a problem, that is: id on json taken there first id on json and repeated as many number of id in database.

Comment: Sorry, I cannot understand what you say about "id on json taken there first id on json and repeated as many number of id in database" . You could for example with some example data to help explain your issues.

Comment: This is partially the id I am debugging: https://1drv.ms/u/s!Auqiv8Ukng7U-V3LJYRRxd2iFHGH
Note: id db is id on database, while id json is id on json. The one experiencing the problem is the id on json, that is, just take the first json id and it is repeated up to a number of id in the database

Comment: Did you mean, if you got one Json record, for example, with id=3217 in Json, and with the code snippet you got all ids on database and didn't find a record that id is 3217, so that you will insert this record and a new id in database generated for example 27. If in this case, you should  replace the id in database with id from json, for example, for the new record inserted, the id should be 3217 and after then this record will not be inserted again.

Comment: Or you should have one column saved the id number special for id from Json, for example named `JsonId`, and every time you want to insert a new record, you should get all `JsonId` from the database to judge if a same record already inserted.

Comment: Yes, I want to like the second option. I want if the id on json is not in the database, then the id on json is inserted in the database, for example: if on json there is id: 3217, 3216, 3215 and after checked on database id 3215 exist in database, then id 3217 and 3216 inserted on the database (so id 3215 does not need to be added/replace)